# how to preselect a specific printer from webapplication

Tags: java, printing, itext, printdialog

Different type of pdf files are generated using iText on the serverside and send over ResponsOutputStream. On the clientside, the printdialog is shown (at least on most viewer), and the defaultprinter is selected. Some pdfs should be printed on labelprinter, other on a desktopprinter. Is it possible to preselect a different printer when the printdialog shows up?

I've tried this for a desktop java application and it worked, but i'm not able to do this from serverside.

```
    ec.setResponseContentType("application/pdf"); 
    ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="labels.pdf"); 
    outStream = ec.getResponseOutputStream();
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outStream);

    PdfAction action = new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG);
    writer.setOpenAction(action);
```

same result using this instruction as I doesn't find a solution to preselect specific printer using Javascript

```
    writer.setOpenAction(PdfAction.javaScript("this.print(true);", writer));
```

the default printer or last used printer is always selected

Comment: Have you tried using the `printParams` argument of the `print` method and setting the `printerName` property therein to the client-side printer name? Cf. the [Adobe Acrobat SDK JavaScript™ for Acrobat® API Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/AcrobatDC_js_api_reference.pdf).

Comment: TX a lot, this works like a charm

Comment: Great! I made this an actual answer instead of a mere comment; you can accept it by clicking the tick at its upper left, under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Adobe Acrobat SDK JavaScript™ for Acrobat® API Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/AcrobatDC_js_api_reference.pdf) the `Doc` method `print` also has a `printParams` parameter

> `printParams` (optional, Acrobat 6.0) The PrintParams object containing the settings to use for
>   printing. If this parameter is passed, any other parameters are ignored.

According to an example in that entry one can use this parameter to select a printer:

> #### Example 2 (Acrobat 6.0)
>
> Print current document to a known printer.
>
> ```
> var pp = this.getPrintParams();
> pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.automatic;
> pp.printerName = "hp officejet d series";
> this.print(pp);
> ```

Thus, if you know the client-side printer name, you can set it as demonstrated in this example.

PS: Most likely your code runs in a non-privileged context; thus, the `pp.interactive` will be ignored, you won't be able to trigger an automatic print job.

Comment: indeed, I can't get it printed automatically, but being able to set the printername is allready a big improvement.